# performance change with respect to instance of class

Tags: c#

**Student.cs**

```
class Student
{
   public int getAge()
   {
      return 10;
   }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Student s = new Student();
      int a = s.getAge();
      int b = new Student().getAge();
   }
}
```

will there be any performance difference when a class is accessed in the above ways

Comment: You create a `Student` instance in both cases and call `getAge()`. Why do you expect some difference here?

Comment: What kind of "security" differences are you thinking about?

Comment: Why do you worry about performance in such a minor case? Premature optimization [is evil](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/80084/156546). Postpone it until you have to write critical code and much more experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will there be any performance or security difference when a class is accessed in the above ways

No.

One way to look for performance difference is by observing the IL statements generated while compiling given code. When you compile the program in debug mode, you do get a slight difference between those two ways of getting age:

```
.locals init (
    [0] class Student,
    [1] int32,
    [2] int32
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: callvirt instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_000d: stloc.1
IL_000e: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0013: call instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_0018: stloc.2
IL_0019: ret
```

Notice here that statements until `IL_000d` are for assignment of variables `s` and `a`. Statements `IL_000e` and `IL_0013` are for assignment of variable `b`. Notice the absence of intermediate statements to assign local variables in the latter.

However, as you compile the code with release configuration, the difference completely disappears as the compiler can easily determine that variables `s`, `a` and `b` are not used in any subsequent statements.

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0005: callvirt instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_000a: pop
IL_000b: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0010: call instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_0015: pop
IL_0016: ret
```

---

Even if you were to indicate that variables `a` and `b` are to be used later-on, the IL code remains identical for both cases.

For example, if the source code is modified as follows:

```
Student s = new Student();
int a = s.getAge();
int b = new Student().getAge();
Console.WriteLine(a);
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The IL now changes to,

```
IL_0000: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0005: callvirt instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_000a: stloc.0
IL_000b: newobj instance void Student::.ctor()
IL_0010: call instance int32 Student::getAge()
IL_0015: ldloc.0
IL_0016: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_001b: call void [System.Console]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
IL_0020: ret
```

---

So I would say there shouldn't be any performance difference between those two cases.

Regarding security, the only difference I observe is the absence of the instance object being stored in the second case. But that shouldn't make any difference either.